# Django, django oscar & Digital Ocean

Tags: python, css, django, digital-ocean, django-oscar

1. I am using Digital Ocean servers to hosts my site. When I run the site with debug = True, it runs fine but when I set it to False, it gives internal server error. I have put my domain name and IP in list of allowed hosts. Any suggestions?
2. Also, I have collected the static files for django admin and django oscar using `manage.py collectstatic` in `static` folder and they are being served properly. But, I have put some other files too in the same folder which include favicon, logo images etc and few css files. The css files are being served properly but the logo and favicon gives a 403(forbidden) error. Again, suggestions?

Comment: bit of code could help us

Comment: @sammy What part of code? I looked into the error log files of nginx and it simply shows that a request was made to the image file and a 403 was returned. For the first problem, there is nothing in the log files.

Comment: code of HTML page,url.py, settings.py,etc.. I want to see how you have tried and may be help you out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Apache and mod_wsgi, then your /static/ folder and/or some images in it probably do not grant permission to the Apache user to serve them.

Try this:

```
chown -R www-data /path/to/folder/static
```